# JSON loop through single object

Tags: javascript, json

How can i get the second values (dates) in a javascript array?

I am new to this and i can't get it to work.

```
{"0":"11-28-2012","4":"11-29-2012","10":"12-03-2012"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to do this by simply doing `json_object[1]`.

Comment: See this question: [loop-through-javascript-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)

Comment: What do you mean by "second dates"? The object you have does have no ordered values, and no key "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple loop is below. You should check that the object hasOwnProperty which is important for more complicated objects.

If your object is called obj:

```
obj = {"0":"11-28-2012","4":"11-29-2012","10":"12-03-2012"}; 
for (var i in obj) {
    console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

Or without the loop:

```
obj = {"0":"11-28-2012","4":"11-29-2012","10":"12-03-2012"};
console.log(obj[0]); // displays "11-28-2012"
```

Comment: You should not name the object "`arr`", as it is no array.

Comment: You are completely correct, I have updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, but i cant get it to work. I have a PHP that does json_encode on array, and then when i console.log() the returned array via ajax i get that object returned, but i cant loop through it..http://jsfiddle.net/qL6dk/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get your fiddle to work for me. What happens when you try to loop through it?

Comment: it looks like its returning parts of string..it does not recognize it as object..

Comment: i got it to work..for (i in ret)
                       {
                            console.log(ret[i].attributes.datum);
                       }

Comment: Nice one, there must be more to the object than specified.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the order of keys is nondeterministic. if you really want, you can use underscore [values](http://underscorejs.org/#values) function

```
_.values(obj)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure want do you want. But if you want to get date in `month-date-year` use `split()`.

```
var jsonDate = {"0":"11-28-2012","4":"11-29-2012","10":"12-03-2012"};

console.log(jsonDate["0"].split('-')[1]); //28
console.log(jsonDate["4"].split('-')[1]); //29
console.log(jsonDate["10"].split('-')[1]); //03
```